# Prevent UISearchBar to move up covering the Navbar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm quite new to Swift and iOS Development and, on a project I am working on,
I want to use a searchbar, that I had to add programmatically because the old method seems to be deprecated in iOS 8.
I've managed to make it working, but I don't like that the searchbar, when triggered, shift to the top of the view, and the status bar becomes transparent.

[image: Here is an example.]

I'd like just to block it under the navbar.
The code I'm using to create the Searchbar is the following:

```
self.resultSearchController = ({
        // creo un oggetto di tipo UISearchController
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        // rimuove la tableView di sottofondo in modo da poter successivamente visualizzare gli elementi cercati
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        // il searchResultsUpdater, ovvero colui che gestirà gli eventi di ricerca, sarà la ListaTableViewController (o self)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self

        // impongo alla searchBar, contenuta all'interno del controller, di adattarsi alle dimensioni dell'applicazioni
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        // atacco alla parte superiore della TableView la searchBar
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        // restituisco il controller creato
        return controller
    })()
```

Can anyone help me?
(Thanks)

Comment: Does adding self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone to your view controller help?

Comment: @Danilo no, it doesn't do anything (apparently). Is it `controller.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None` ?

Comment: should be in viewDidLoad in your view controller (not the search controller)

Comment: It makes the status bar black.

Comment: If you want the status bar in a different style use UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
```

in your view controllers (not the search controllers) `viewDidLoad`

This will prohibit the table view from being "pulled" underneath your search bar and status bar.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5, it's rather this:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```